# cannot show html tags

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I was able to display data from database using codeigniter and jquery. The only problem is that I cannot show html tags as well. For example in my database I have following data `"Apple<br>Peach"` but when I display that info to user it shows
 
"Apple
Peach"
Is there a function that can help me to show html tag `<br>` as well ?

Update:

Please check my code below and advise me where I should use htmlentities() function so that it can display html tags for elements of data array:

Model:

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Controller:

```
$data["results"] = $this->model_a->get_info();              
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the contents from db (which has html) with this function: [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities)

for example: `echo htmlentities('Apple<br>Peach');`

will produce: `Apple&lt;br&gt;Peach`

which will render on-screen as: `Apple<br>Peach`

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you please check the update of my question?

Comment: can you `var_dump($data["results"]);` and show me what's in it? or show me the resulting json string. I am not sure what you are trying to encode as htmlentities, that's why.

Comment: Json returns this data : {"results":[{"id":"1","title":"Fruits"," content":"Apple<br>Peach"}]} I want to display <br> tag on the screen as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function htmlentities(). Have a look at the [manual](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Please note that by default the data will be returned using the ISO-8859-1 character set. You might want to change the third parameter to UTF-8.

For example:

> $html = "Some text";
>
> echo htmlentities($html);